# Phone number formatting in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.4-kitkat

I have been trying to get

**XML File**

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phoneEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:inputType="phone"/>
```

**Java**

```
 etContact = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.phoneEditText );
 etContact.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() );
```

To successfully format the number entered by the user but it fails to perform the formatting on my Nexus 5 test device, while on lower API levels it does work. I am not sure if this has been changed of phased out since KitKat but it refuses to work now. Is there a work around or additional calls to enable this to work on KitKat?

Comment: It works as expected on my 4.4.2 device.

Comment: Strange, it does nothing on mine. The only attribute set on my xml is padding.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: what is happening inside watcher??

Comment: I was doing some reading and that is actually a `TextWatcher` for formatting numbers in android see doc here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html#PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher()